# Merge dictionaries where keys have same value

Tags: python, dictionary

I only found questions where people wanted to merge dictionaries with the criteria "key", but I want to merge dictionaries depending on the same value (where I don't know what value exactly).

Lets say I have a List containing dictionaries

```
myList = [
  {'key1': 'v1', 'key2': 'v2'},
  {'key1': 'v1', 'key2': 'v3'},
  {'key1': 'v1', 'key2': 'v4'},
  {'key1': 'v5', 'key2': 'v6'},
  {'key1': 'v7', 'key2': 'v8'}
]
```

now I want to merge the dictionaries where the keys have the same value, e.g., `key1` has the value `v1` but I don't know what 'v1' is so i can't use a criteria like `=='v1'`.

Resulting in

```
myMergedList = [
  {'key1': 'v1', 'key2': ('v2','v3','v4')},
  {'key1': 'v5', 'key2': 'v6'},
  {'key1': 'v7', 'key2': 'v8'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
myList = [
    {"key1": "v1", "key2": "v2"},
    {"key1": "v1", "key2": "v3"},
    {"key1": "v1", "key2": "v4"},
    {"key1": "v5", "key2": "v6"},
    {"key1": "v7", "key2": "v8"},
]

out = {}
for d in myList:
    out.setdefault(d["key1"], []).append(d["key2"])

out = [
    {"key1": k, "key2": v[0] if len(v) == 1 else tuple(v)}
    for k, v in out.items()
]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'key1': 'v1', 'key2': ('v2', 'v3', 'v4')}, 
 {'key1': 'v5', 'key2': 'v6'}, 
 {'key1': 'v7', 'key2': 'v8'}]
```